# Как сделать элементы choises формы Django динамическими?

Tags: python, django, form

Мне нужно сделать форму Django, в которой два поля: region и city.
Оба поля предлагают варианты из выпадающего списка.
Поле city должно быть доступно только после выбора region и варианты поля city должны зависеть от выбранного ранее region.

Можно ли это осуществить не прибегая к js?

Comment: Нет, нельзя. Хотя может и можно ченить набудрить на css3, но поверь, это будет тот еще треш

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всем спасибо. В итоге все равно пришлось тащить немного js для ajax запросов.

Answer (score 2):

Можно воспользоваться готовыми компонентами. Например django_select2
https://django-select2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/extra.html#customizing-a-form

Формально .js будет использоваться все равно. Но не нужно будет его писать самостоятельно, он будет подкидываться из исопльзуемого компонента.